# Application Loader issue: Productutil binary

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store, application-loader

I'm trying to submit my app on Mac App Store. I can't upload my application with Application Loader because ''The productutil binary must exist and must be executable: /usr/libexec/productutil''

Why? How can I fix issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happen to me, this is how I solved it:
just copy `productutil` from `{xcode-install-directory}/usr/libexec/` to `/usr/libexec/`

Answer (score 0):

usr/libexec/productutil is necessary for building .pkgs. You can get it by reinstalling Xcode with everything checked (or maybe just the Unix Tools, but I haven't tried it). Note that it puts it in the usr directory where xcode is installed, not /usr. This should be what you need, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4 you are able to upload applications directly to the app store, just use that since it won't have any errors like this.
Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442